# Optimal way of including test file dependencies in a Python package

Tags: python, django, package

I have a Django app which has the following structure:

```
app/
    tests/
        files/
            image.jpg
        ...
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.in
    ...
```

If I create a package, by default, `image.jpg` won't be included since it is not a Python file. I've then added this file in `MANIFEST.in` and it is indeed included in the package, but since it is a test file, my thoughts are that it shouldn't be included in the package from the `MANIFEST.in` file.

These being said, what's the optimal way of including test-related non-Python files (e.g.: images) in Python packages?

Comment: Perhaps this http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data ?

Comment: `package_data` files are added to the `MANIFEST.in` so more or less it's the same approach to the one I presented above.

Comment: Is there something that forces you to use image files in your tests in the first place? I generally either mock the image file or create a random image in memory.

Comment: Well, not actually, but it would be simpler to simply have an existing image and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's part of a Django reusable app - do you want users to run `manage.py test yourapp` and have the tests pass?

If so, you probably want to distribute the test image. If not, you probably don't want to distribute it at all, so you can just remove it from `MANIFEST.in`.

Comment: That's the case. Tests depend on that image. Thought that test-related things should be included in the package some other way.

Comment: Why would it be distributed differently? You always want it to be distributed (so that tests pass), so there's nothing else needed.